# Django many-to-many reverse of the same model?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

Is it possible to get the reverse of a django many-to-many of the same model?

For example, I have a product that is called Product Range of XY that is part of Product Range X and Product Range Y.

So far I have the following:

## model.py

```
class HeadwallRange(Product, ContentTyped):
    child_ranges = models.ManyToManyField("HeadwallRange", blank=True, related_name="child_range_products")
```

## views.py

```
product_range = HeadwallRange.objects.filter(child_range_products = page.id).first()
```

I can go in the "normal" direction (i.e from Product Range X I can get Product Range XY) but given Product Range XY is there any way to get  Product Range X?

Comment: First, you really don't want to replace builtin names in the your application namespace. However, you can try `range.child_range_products.all()`

Comment: Thanks @OluwafemiSule obvious mistake so I've changed that reference. Unfortunately your code will still return the "normal" direction of that relationship, I need the inverse of this.